# regular expression how to get substring?

Tags: java, regex

This are my example data:

```
406/FG-2000

411/FA-2120

XX-226/2012-DFDF

OASDV-279/1016-FDFFD
```

how can with regex (only regex) in java i parse

```
406/FG-2000 -> 406 (from begining to /)

411/FA-2120 -> 411 (from begining to /)

XX-226/2012-DFDF -> 226 (from - to /)

OASDV-279/1016-FDFFD -> 279 (from - to /)
```

this are two rules. (from begining to /) or (from - to /)

Comment: According to your testdata: is a third rule "must be digits"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code does what you asked for:

```
input.replaceAll(".*(^|-)(.*?)/.*", "$2")
```

If you want to restrict it to digits only, change the matching regex to `".*(^|-)(\\d*?)/.*"`

Here's a test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] inputs = { "406/FG-2000", "411/FA-2120", "XX-226/2012-DFDF", "OASDV-279/1016-FDFFD" };
    for (String input : inputs)
        System.out.println(input.replaceAll(".*(^|-)(.*?)/.*", "$2"));
}
```

Output:

```
406
411
226
279
```

Comment: i tested here: http://www.roblocher.com/technotes/regexp.aspx but i get group 1 and group 2 as result. Why not just 1 result?

Comment: groups are bracketed expressions. there are two groups in the regex, but the first one is there only because of the "OR" expression. the second group is the "real" capturing group

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
(^|-)[0-9]+/
```

It will match any numbers from the beginning or from a - to the /